# Group by with UNION in Mariadb

Tags: pivot, mariadb

I have this query:

```
select  item_code, item_name, First, Second, Third, `Fourth` from (
            (SELECT t.item_code, i.item_name, t.actual_qty AS `First`, '' AS `Second`, '' AS `Third`, '' AS `Fourth` FROM tabBin t JOIN `tabItem` i ON i.name = t.item_code WHERE t.warehouse = "Finished Goods")
            UNION 
            (SELECT t.item_code, i.item_name, '' AS `First`, t.actual_qty AS `Second`, '' AS `Third`, '' AS `Fourth` FROM tabBin t JOIN `tabItem` i ON i.name = t.item_code WHERE t.warehouse = "Tank 01 - 1200 KG")
            UNION 
            (SELECT t.item_code, i.item_name, '' AS `First`, '' AS `Second`, t.actual_qty AS `Third`, '' AS `Fourth` FROM tabBin t JOIN `tabItem` i ON i.name = t.item_code WHERE t.warehouse = "Tank 02 - 1200 KG")
            UNION 
            (SELECT t.item_code, i.item_name, '' AS `First`, '' AS `Second`, '' AS `Third`, t.actual_qty AS `Fourth` FROM tabBin t JOIN `tabItem` i ON i.name = t.item_code WHERE t.warehouse = "Tank 03 - 1200 KG")) as temp
            GROUP BY temp.item_code, temp.item_name, temp.First, temp.Second, temp.Third, temp.Fourth
```

And this is the output:

```
item_code  item_name  first, second, third, fourth
fg-plu        PLUM                         30.000000
fg-plu        PLUM                  40.000000   
fg-plu        PLUM           10.000000      
fg-plu        PLUM   1248.00
```

I want to group by the `item_code` and `item_name` or just `item_code`.

Comment: Don’t use UNION then, but a normal subselect …?

Comment: Will return a lot of rows. I don't know if with subselect this will work

Comment: This is called "pivoting" -- follow the tag I added.

Answer (score 0):

This really appears to be a pivot query in disguise.  Just use `MAX` with `CASE` expressions to get the output you want:

```
SELECT
    t.item_code,
    i.item_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.warehouse='Finished Goods'    THEN t.actual_qty END) AS first,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.warehouse='Tank 01 - 1200 KG' THEN t.actual_qty END) AS second,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.warehouse='Tank 02 - 1200 KG' THEN t.actual_qty END) AS third,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.warehouse='Tank 03 - 1200 KG' THEN t.actual_qty END) AS fourth
FROM tabBin t
INNER JOIN tabItem i
    ON i.name = t.item_code
GROUP BY
    t.item_code,
    i.item_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved with

```
enter code Select i.item_name,IFNULL((select b.actual_qty as i2total
       from `tabItem` as i2
            join  `tabBin` as b on b.item_code = i2.item_code AND  i2.item_code = i2.item_code
       where b.warehouse = "Finished Goods" AND  i2.item_code = i.item_code),0) foa, IFNULL((select b.actual_qty as i2total
       from `tabItem` as i2
            join  `tabBin` as b on b.item_code = i2.item_code AND  i2.item_code = i2.item_code
       where b.warehouse = "Toros" AND  i2.item_code = i.item_code),0) toros, (foa + toros) AS total FROM `tabItem` as i WHERE  i.item_group = "products" GROUP BY  i.item_name, foa, toros ;
```

Thanks everyone for help.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with your original question.  What is this query supposed to be doing?